# Modifying field options using FormTypeExtensions

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I know there's no clean way to do this after the form has been built using FormEvents however is there a way to mainpulate the options passed to a form using `FormTypeExtensionInterface::buildForm` before it has been completely built?

e.g: I will use this to set multiple options to specific values when another option is set in the form e.g: when the option `"helper"` is set true set the `"label"` option to "helper" and set `"disabled"` option to `true`

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  You can pass options to `createForm()` and do things before the builder

Comment: @JasonRoman I added an example use case in the question Description.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is pass the option to your form when you create it.  For example, in your controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), null, array('helper' => true));
```

Then in your `buildForm` function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('myfield', null, array(
            'label'    => ($options['helper']) ? 'helper' : 'mylabel',
            'disabled' => ($options['helper']) ? true : false,
        ))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'helper' => false,
    ));
}
```

The only thing is, this is a global option for the entire form.  Did you mean that you want this option for every individual field?

Comment: I want this option to take effect for all form(field) types.So I don't have to check that option every time I'm creating new form.